# Where and who can I trade in my Korok Seeds to?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Zelda: Breath of the Wild, where in Hyrule can I hand in my Korok Seeds to gain rewards?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

You give the seeds to Hestu.  He can be found at:

- [1<sup>st</sup> location](https://youtu.be/wcQd-JrziYk?t=7m23s) is on the way to Kakariko Village in West Necluda.
- 2<sup>nd</sup> location is after completing his side quest and giving him enough Korok Seeds, he will attempt to return home but will get lost.  It appears his second location seems to alter for players.  Various sources, state he can be found at the Wetlands Stable, Woodlands Stable, or Riverside Stable next.  All of these stables are along the Hylia River, which is what Hestu said he would follow to get back to his home.  It's unclear if he will visit one, two, or all of these locations before making it to his third.  Nonetheless, here are some sources showing and discussing his possible second location(s):

  - This [linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uE68xYbYPx0) for his second location shows where he will be for the Riverside Stable location.
  - [This map](https://zeldamaps.com/?game=BotW&marker=331&zoom=6) shows he can be present at the Woodlands Stable.
  - Various sources also suggest the Wetland Stable, such as [here](http://disq.us/p/1gomyx9), [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75067757), [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302150/163757) to another question, and [the Wiki](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Hestu) for Hestu.

It's possible he may skip this location if you give him enough seeds at the first location and will progress to Korok Forest (the third location).  [According to IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Hestu), he will perform 6 upgrades here, but [other sources](http://disq.us/p/1gpkvgx) say 5.  After that, he will move.

- [3<sup>rd</sup> location](https://youtu.be/iSD9EwsVmWk) is in Korok Village/Forest.  Currently, this is believed to be his final location (as it is his home). To reach it, you must go through the Lost Woods.

<sub>[(Main Source)](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/zelda-breath-wild-find-hestu-locations/)</sub>

---

According to the [Wiki](https://zeldawiki.org/Korok_Seed) for the seeds, you give them to the Korok [Hestu](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Hestu).

> When Link is given one, he is asked to return it to the Korok Hestu.

You will also need to get him his Maracas as well before you get a reward.

> If Link returns him the missing Maracas and gives him a Korok Seed, Hestu will add one slot to either his Weapon, Bow, or Shield stashes.

Hestu moves after you give him a certain amount of seeds. At the moment, there is currently three locations that I could find. [This link](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/zelda-breath-wild-find-hestu-locations/) contains some of them.

Hestu's [first location](http://www.gamersheroes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Zelda-Breath-Of-The-Wild-Where-To-Find-Hestu-Locations-Location-1.jpg) is on the way to Kakariko Village.  This is where you will get his side quest for finding his Maracas.

After completing his side quest for finding his Maracas and giving him a certain amount of seeds (possibly two), he will attempt to go back to his home, but will get lost.  His [next location](http://www.gamersheroes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Where-To-Find-Hestu-Location-2.jpg) will be either next to a Shrine to the north west of Batrea Lake near the Riverside Stable, the Woodland Stable, or the Wetland Stable.  It is unclear at this time if he will stop at all of these locations, or just one of them before making his way to the third location.  Also, if you gave him enough seeds at his first location, he may skip this location and proceed to the third.

Hestu's third location is within Korok Village.  To reach it, you need to go through the Lost Woods, which appears to be a navigational challenge.  This is also currently believed to be his final location since it is his home and according to [this website](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/korok-seed-breath-wild-locations-where-find-hestu-and-how-solve-puzzles-all-900-587100), he takes permanent residence here:

> ...finally taking permanent residence within the Korok Forest.

Comment: Where in Hyrule is Hestu?  Ive met Hestu, but forgotten where he is in the world

Comment: I think you actually have to do 2 upgrades on the road to Kakariko Village before he moves... or at least for me he didn't mention leaving until I'd done 2 upgrades.

Comment: @TimmyJim this is an excellent answer you have been building here, I must thank you for the work you have put in.  If we can confirm that Korok Forest is definitely Hestu's last location, you will get the tick and the bounty.

Comment: @TimmyJim FYI, on my way to the Korok forest last night, I found Hestu just behind Wetlands Stable, which is a whole new location I am guessing? Still havent made it to Korok forest yet so I don't know if this is his last location yet. (and if you get a chance to play BotW, do so, its excellent!)

Comment: @Jimmery Because of the data provided on the official guide of the game I can confirm that the last location is the Korok Forest.

Comment: If you've done things in a different order and got the sword before meeting Hestu at his second location, you may need to come bak to the original Hestu location before he moves to the forest.

Answer (score 6):

As stated [over in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302174/56730), he moves to Korok Forest, north of Hyrule Castle. If you're going there for the first time, he'll be on the right side of the town.