# Where does Hestu go after the first encounter?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Hestu, as in the guy you give Korok seeds to. After I first met him and completed his quest, he's no longer in that same spot. Where can I find him?

Comment: Not a direct dupe, but your answer is also here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302086/163757

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**After Hestu leaves the location where you meet him, look for Hestu near the [Riverside Stable](https://zeldamaps.com/?game=BotW&marker=287&zoom=6) north of Batrea Lake.**

After you expand your inventory, Hestu tells you he needs to go home to his Grandpa in Korok Forest. If you talk to him again afterward, you can ask him how to get there:

[image: Hestu discusses Korok Forest - The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild]
[image: Hestu discusses Korok Forest - The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild]
[image: Hestu discusses Korok Forest - The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild]

On the way, he stops near [Riverside Stable](https://zeldamaps.com/?game=BotW&marker=287&zoom=6) along the Hylia river. After you upgrade your inventory a few more times, he continues his journey.

**Eventually, Hestu will make it to [Korok Forest](https://zeldamaps.com/?game=BotW&marker=377&zoom=6). To get there, follow the Hylia River north.**

Comment: @TimmyJim Thanks for the info. Added the clarifying info to my post.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://zeldawiki.org/Hestu) wiki, he can be found again at Wetland Stable due to getting lost on the way to Korok Forest.

> Hestu will only allow Link to upgrade a few times before announcing that he needs to get back to Korok Forest. However, he gets lost on the way, and is next found at Wetland Stable, in the westernmost part of Lanayru. He allows Link to get several more upgrades before remembering the way back to Korok Forest and leaving again.

Additional information is found on the "wiki". I'm unsure if thats the official zelda wiki.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. I found him at his initial place and then next in Korok Forest.

Comment: @Seiyria I based my answer on the forum in the link. I don't play this game.

Comment: I'm commenting to clarify for other people that might come across this answer.

Comment: Good comment ;)