# Is Hestu always in the Lost Woods?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Even if you don't talk to Hestu near Kakariko or the Stable afterwards, when you go to the lost woods will he be there? Or do you have to talk to him at both places before he shows up in the lost woods?

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302085/where-and-who-can-i-trade-in-my-korok-seeds-to.  I would imagine that skipping the first two locations would make it so he is not in the Lost Woods until you do those two locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [Hestu](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Hestu) will not always end up in the [Lost Woods](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Lost_Woods) (or more accurately, in [Korok Forest](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Korok_Forest)). According to the [IGN wiki](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Hestu):

> Hestu will finally make it to Korok Forest after you visit him at either Stable.

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302086/163757) summarizes Hestu's locations in great detail, though I will summarize them briefly below:

After initially meeting Hestu south of [Kakariko Village](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Kakariko_Village), and completing the [Priceless Maracas Quest](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/The_Priceless_Maracas), he will then move to a location south of Kakariko village (along the winding path) in west Necluda.

After 2 upgrades here, Hestu then moves to the left bank of the Hylia River, just northeast of [Riverside Stable](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Riverside_Stable). Sometimes Hestu can also be found at the [Woodlands Stable](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKi66CjOPTAhUo4oMKHYsIBE8QFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fca.ign.com%2Fwikis%2Fthe-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild%2FWoodland_Stable&usg=AFQjCNHD1JP6o0b0Y3PWFDENlLTluOHiEg). And [some sources](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Hestu) suggest he can also sometimes be found at the [Wetlands Stable](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid3O-djePTAhWL1IMKHScDAPAQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fca.ign.com%2Fwikis%2Fthe-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild%2FWetland_Stable&usg=AFQjCNGsuPCcn4NWq3lyPVJ_CTYg6cpBgw). Nevertheless, more inventory upgrades are now available for purchase.

Finally, Hestu will make it to [Korok Forest](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Korok_Forest) where he will remain for the rest of the game.

Answer (score 1):

Hestu will not be at the Lost Woods before you find him near Kakariko Village. This makes sense, since he's trying to get his maracas back and they are guarded in a chest in a nearby monster camp. Without his maracas, he can't upgrade your inventory.

As for his second location, it's less clear whether this is required. I suspect that if you let enough in-game days pass, it's possible that he may eventually end up in the Korok Forest without any further prompting. However, finding him at a stable and giving him more seeds will definitely speed up the process of getting him home faster.